# Sqoop Export works in command line but fails in Oozie Workflow

Tags: hadoop, workflow, sqoop, cloudera, oozie

I tried lot of things in order to make my Sqoop Export work, here is the command that works in bash:

```
sqoop export --connect jdbc:mysql://localhost/monapp --username root --password cloudera --table results --direct --export-dir hdfs://quickstart.cloudera:8020/data/aggregated_data/ --driver com.mysql.jdbc.Driver --m 1
```

But when I use an Oozie Workflow as follows it doesn't work and I can't see any errors in the log file (/var/log/sqoop2/) :

```
<action name="export">
    <sqoop xmlns="uri:oozie:sqoop-action:0.2">
        <job-tracker>quickstart.cloudera:8032</job-tracker>
        <name-node>hdfs://quickstart.cloudera:8020</name-node>
        <arg>export</arg>
        <arg>--connect</arg>
        <arg>jdbc:mysql://localhost/monapp</arg>
        <arg>--username</arg>
        <arg>root</arg>
        <arg>--password</arg>
        <arg>cloudera</arg>
        <arg>--table</arg>
        <arg>results</arg>
        <arg>--export-dir</arg>
        <arg>hdfs://quickstart.cloudera:8020/data/aggregated_data/</arg>
        <arg>--driver</arg>
        <arg>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</arg>
        <arg>-m</arg>
        <arg>1</arg>
    </sqoop>
    <ok to="end" />
    <error to="error" />
</action>
```

Please tell me if I need to check a log file? I will edit my question.

Comment: I'm using Cloudera QuickStart VM 5.8

Comment: Oozie runs Sqoop **V1** i.e. the original fat client. The V2 was an attempt by Cloudera to build a (thin) client/server replacement but -- like many Cloudera attempts -- it is now a zombie project, forget about it.

Comment: You need to check, first the status and logs of the Oozie job, then the status and logs of the actual YARN job (spawned by Oozie to actually run Sqoop somewhere on the cluster).

Comment: Ok I see now, I switched to HortonWorks and I'm still stuck with the java part (mapreduce) in the workflow but I think the sqoop part will work since they use sqoop V1.

Comment: For the record, Sqoop V1 is present in _all_ distros... And works exactly the same way. Switching to Horton makes no difference whatsoever (except for default configs and minor version differences).